# Форматирование вывода в Ruby

Tags: массивы, ruby, строки

Нужно отформатировать вывод так, чтобы он был читабельным (желательно похожим на табличку) и сохранить его в файл .txt. Как это сделать?

Вот моя функция:

```
def output (array)
  File.open('result.txt', 'w') do |infile|
    array.each do |item|
        item.each do |jtem|
            infile.write("#{jtem}\t")
        end
        infile.write("\n")
    end
  end  
end
```

Проблема заключается в том, что из-за разной длины строк "\t" работает не корректно и вывод съезжает.

Примечание: аргумент функции (array) это массив массивов, его элементы (подмассивы) имеют примерно такой вид:

["1223", "Person_name", "Person_surname",  "1234554321", "Person_group", "One_more_string"]

Answer (score 1):

Используйте форматирование для строк и если надо разделитель, то его тоже не забывайте добавлять. Для интервалов между строк будет так: "%10s" % [jtem] ,где 10 - количество символов которое будет занимать вывод.

```
def output (array)
  File.open('result.txt', 'w') do |infile|
    array.each do |item|
        item.each do |jtem|
            infile.write("%15s" % [jtem])
        end
        infile.write("\n")
    end
  end  
end
```

Comment: @malworm Отметьте, пожалуйста, ответ как принятый (зеленая галочка слева от ответа), если он решил ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться функцией из [гема "mll"](https://rubygems.org/gems/mll), который призван реализовывать ф-ционал [Grid из Wolfram Mathematica](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html):

```
array = [
  ["1223", "Vasya", "Ivanov", "1234554321", "group_A", "One_more_string"],
  ["12345", "Yura", "Noob", "1234554321", "group_BB", "And_another_one"],
]

require "mll"
puts MLL::grid[array, spacings: [2,0]]

  1223    Vasya   Ivanov   1234554321   group_A    One_more_string  
  12345   Yura     Noob    1234554321   group_BB   And_another_one
```

В [RSpec-ах](https://github.com/Nakilon/mll/blob/master/spec/_spec.rb#L949) можно посмотреть параметры, доступные на данный момент.